# Json schema validation in ref with specific attribute

Tags: json-schema-validator

Please help. Can't find answer

I have next schema. And somedict repeat in several somelist, but only in one I need to check that in somedict has specific attribute "someproperties2"
I create this schema, but when I make validation I get error 
[{'somedict': {'$ref': '#/definitions/somedict'}}, {'someproperties2': {'type': 'array'}, 'required': ['someproperties2']}] is not of type 'object'
Please help

```
schema = {
    "definitions": {
        'somelist': {"type": "array",
                     'items': {"type": "object",
                               "properties": {'somestring': {'type': 'string'},
                                              'somedict': {"$ref": "#/definitions/analyticTerm"}
                                              },
                               'required': ['somestring', 'somedict'],
                               "additionalProperties": False
                               }
                     },
        'somedict': {"type": "object",
                     "properties": {
                         'someproperties1': {'type': 'string'},
                         'someproperties2': {'type': 'array'},
                     },
                     'required': ['someproperties1'],
                     "additionalProperties": False
                     }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        'somelist': {"$ref": "#/definitions/somelist",
                     'properties': {
                         'allOf':
                             [
                                 {'somedict': {"$ref": "#/definitions/somedict"}
                                  },
                                 {'someproperties2': {'type': 'array'},
                                  "required": ["someproperties2"]
                                  }
                             ]
                     }
                     }
    }
}


request = {
    "somelist": [
        {
            "somestring": "Y",
            "somedict": {
                "someproperties1": "Name",
                "someproperties2": {
                    "someproperties2": "YNU"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your tag search code, please?

Comment: What do you mean about tag search cod?

Comment: your validation code.

Comment: jsonschema.validate(request, schema)